# Take input a batch file and output that input to another batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Sorry for the messy title.

I want to efficiently take input from another batch file/window (example: a choice command inside a batch file) and send it to the other batch file. Essentially it would "type" it in the other window. Now, I can't just have the first batch file open a new one, because if I did that I would just open another java instance

The code for the first batch file:

```
:menu
cls
echo.
echo Please select option using keys 1 or 2:
echo. [1] Start server
echo. [2] Stop server
echo. [3] Say "hi"!
choice /C 12 /N
if %errorlevel%==1 goto start-server
if %errorlevel%==2 goto stop-server
if %errorlevel%==3 goto test-command
goto menu

:start-server
echo Starting server...
start start.bat
pause
goto menu

:stop-server
echo Stopping server
echo stop > task start.bat
pause
goto menu

:test-command
echo say hi > task start.bat
pause
goto menu
```

The code for the second batch file:

```
@echo off

java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar spigot_server.jar
pause
```

Something like `echo stop > task start.bat`

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve this? I'm willing to use anything other than batch for the first file (since the second one requires it to be a batch script) but I don't want to download anything.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/764392/sending-input-to-command-line-program-from-text-batch-file the first answer to this question suggests "VBScript.SendKeys"

Comment: Have you tried using [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your java server is a console process that accepts redirected stdin input. I'm also assuming your server process will terminate if reading from a file and it reaches the end of the input file. I'm also assuming you do not want to modify your java code.

You cannot use a pipe to communicate between two windows. But you can use a file.

Your master batch script can write commands to an input file that are read by the server. But the server cannot read the commands directly. A sender batch script is needed to relay the commands to the server.

The master script launches the server by STARTing a send script with input redirected to the input file, and the send scripts output is piped to your server process.

The send script is a loop that repeatedly uses FOR /F to read the input file via FINDSTR. FINDSTR reads stdin (which has already been redirected to the input file). The reason this works is because FINDSTR does not reset the file pointer each time it is called. If there are no new commands, then it returns nothing. But if a line has been added to the input file, then FINDSTR will pick it up.

Each command that is added to the input file consists of two parts that are delimited by a colon.

- A command for the send batch script

  - GO tells the send script it is a normal command for the server
  - EXIT tells the send script that it should shut down
- The command for the server

I've opted to combine the master script and sender script into a single script. The script launches the sender by calling itself with a :send argument. If the first argument is :send, then it branches to the sender code.

I don't have your java server code. So for demonstration purposes I have used cmd.exe as my "server". Obviously the commands in my :menu are geared for cmd.exe. You can substitute your java program and change the commands appropriately.

Note that the server window will automatically steal focus when it is STARTed. You must click on the parent window to regain focus so you can enter commands.

```
@echo off
if "%~1" equ ":send" goto :send

setlocal
set "inputFile=input.txt"
set "serverCommand=cmd.exe"

:initMenu
echo(
echo Press one of the option keys
echo  [S] Start server
echo  [Q] Quit
choice /c SQ /n
if errorlevel 2 exit /b
echo Starting server...
echo(
echo You must click on this main window to regain focus.
copy nul "%inputFile%" >nul
start "" cmd /c ""%~f0" :send <"%inputFile%" | cmd"
call :menu
echo Server stopped
goto :initMenu

:menu
echo Press one of the option keys
echo  [D] Date
echo  [T] Time
echo  [P] Ping
echo  [S] Stop server
choice /c DTPS /N
>>"%inputFile%" (
  if errorlevel 4 (
    echo exit:exit
    exit /b
  ) else if errorlevel 3 (
    echo go:ping /n 5 localhost
  ) else if errorlevel 2 (
    echo go:time /t
  ) else (
    echo go:date /t
  )
)
echo(
goto :menu

:send
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in ('findstr "^"') do (
  echo(%%B
  if /i %%A equ exit %%A
)
goto :send
```

Note that the :send routine is continuously polling stdin, so it will peg a processor (or processor core) at nearly 100%. You could add a PING delay in the loop so that it does not hog CPU resources, but then the server will not be as responsive.

---

If your server process does not automatically terminate when it reaches the end of redirected input, then you don't need a sender batch process. You can simply launch your server within your master script using

```
start cmd /c ""yourServerCommand <"%inputFile%""
```

Or if it currently terminates upon reaching end of file, but you are willing to modify the server code, then you could still do the above. You could modify your java code to continuously poll for input, only reading a line if not at end of file. The process would only terminate when it receives some type of exit command.

---

If your server is not a console process, then you will need something like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to send commands to your server window. Or you could roll your own solution with VBScript or JScript and the [SendKeys method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx).

Even if your server process is a console process, you still might want to use AutoIt or SendKeys, as it is more straight forward.

Comment: I can only assume I have received a revenge downvote.

Comment: The downvote was due to your answer being too lengthy, for what I interpreted as a simple question, and based on assumptions.

Comment: @DevilsAdvocate, the amount of content is no criteria for voting; please rely on the quality only!

Comment: @aschipfl I think it is, and it was only part of my criteria anyway. Regardless, I removed the down vote.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first option you supplied did not work unfortunately, but using VBS SendKeys worked great!